# Unknown Log format character '<'

Tags: logging, omnet++

After Installing Omnet++ 5.5.1 in Ubuntu 18.04 I used command

```
./aloha
```

in aloha folder which makes visible a window showing simulation. But instead a simulation a small window also pops out there which says:

> Unknown log format Character '<'

After clicking 'OK' button in that small window, all simulation disappears. What should I change and in which file to enjoy of running them?

[image: ]]

Running of command

```
./aloha -u Cmdenv -c PureAloha1
```

gives the following output

```
OMNeT++ Discrete Event Simulation  (C) 1992-2019 Andras Varga, OpenSim Ltd.
Version: 5.5.1, build: 190613-08ba16f914, edition: Academic Public License -- NOT FOR COMMERCIAL USE
See the license for distribution terms and warranty disclaimer

Setting up Cmdenv...

Loading NED files from .:  4

Preparing for running configuration PureAloha1, run #0...
Assigned runID=PureAloha1-0-20200429-15:35:03-5450
Setting up network "Aloha"...
Initializing...

Running simulation...
** Event #0   t=0   Elapsed: 1.9e-05s (0m 00s)
     Speed:     ev/sec=0   simsec/sec=0   ev/simsec=0
     Messages:  created: 21   present: 21   in FES: 20
** Event #1883904   t=58153.362029057537   Elapsed: 2.00012s (0m 02s)
     Speed:     ev/sec=941903   simsec/sec=29075.1   ev/simsec=32.3955
     Messages:  created: 554290   present: 22   in FES: 21
** Event #3845632   t=118789.916385172084   Elapsed: 4.0002s (0m 04s)
     Speed:     ev/sec=980825   simsec/sec=30317.1   ev/simsec=32.3522
     Messages:  created: 1131461   present: 21   in FES: 20
** Event #5795328   t=179129.824292797549   Elapsed: 6.00028s (0m 06s)
     Speed:     ev/sec=974809   simsec/sec=30168.7   ev/simsec=32.3119
     Messages:  created: 1704996   present: 22   in FES: 20
** Event #7667712   t=236990.771932954743   Elapsed: 8.19047s (0m 08s)
     Speed:     ev/sec=854895   simsec/sec=26418.2   ev/simsec=32.3601
     Messages:  created: 2255936   present: 21   in FES: 20
** Event #9530880   t=294575.408721298404   Elapsed: 10.1952s (0m 10s)
     Speed:     ev/sec=929374   simsec/sec=28724   ev/simsec=32.3553
     Messages:  created: 2804268   present: 21   in FES: 20
** Event #11474176   t=354659.934461976161   Elapsed: 12.2068s (0m 12s)
     Speed:     ev/sec=966040   simsec/sec=29868.9   ev/simsec=32.3427
     Messages:  created: 3375916   present: 22   in FES: 21

<!> Error: simtime_t overflow adding 9.390966485872 to 9223366.078979727235: Result is out of range (-9223372.036854775807,9223372.036854775807), allowed by scale exponent -12 -- in module (aloha::Host) Aloha.host[7] (id=10), at t=9223366.078979727235s, event #298666063

End.
```

Whereas the command

```
./aloha -u Qtenv -c PureAloha1
```

Gives the following output

```
OMNeT++ Discrete Event Simulation  (C) 1992-2019 Andras Varga, OpenSim Ltd.
Version: 5.5.1, build: 190613-08ba16f914, edition: Academic Public License -- NOT FOR COMMERCIAL USE
See the license for distribution terms and warranty disclaimer

Setting up Qtenv...

Loading NED files from .:  4

Loading images from './bitmaps': *: 0 
Loading images from './images': *: 0 
Loading images from '/home/shivanshu/Pictures/Project/omnetpp-5.5.1/images': *: 0  abstract/*: 90  background/*: 4  block/*: 320  device/*: 195  logo/*: 1  maps/*: 9  misc/*: 70  msg/*: 55  old/*: 111  status/*: 28 


End.
```

and the aforementioned window of unknown log format character '<'.Please help.

Comment: First of all try to run simulation in command mode `./aloha -u Cmdenv -c PureAloha1` then show us the results. Then try to run in QT mode using `./aloha -u Qtenv -c PureAloha1`.

Comment: @JerzyD. I hava editted question with your suggeted command output but still the problem is unresolved.Help!!

Comment: Have you done any changes in `omnetpp.ini` in that directory?

Comment: Not at all ! Should i perform any changes in any file ?

Comment: No, don't change ini.

Comment: What should i do to resolve the issue ?

Comment: I have no idea how to resolve your problem. Try to download a fresh OMNeT++, unpack it to new folder and compile. Maybe QT in your system in an issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have probably an OLD `.qtenvrc` in the root of your home directory. try:

```
$ rm ~/.qtenvrc
```

`.qtenvrc` contains various global initialization parameters for QTEnv, including the mentioned logformat parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows go to: `C:/users/user_name/`
then delete the file named: `.qtenvrc`